# Replace specific repeating characters from a string

Tags: c#

I have a string like `"aaa\\\\\\\\test.txt"`.

How do I replace all the repeating `\\` characters by a single `\\`?

I have tried

```
pPath = new Regex("\\{2,}").Replace(pPath, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString());
```

which matches on http://regexstorm.net/tester but doesn't seem to do the trick in my program.

I'm running this on Windows so the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is a `\\`.

Comment: The path directory separator is \. The first \ is just an escape character.

Comment: Yes, but in order to escape the single \ in my regex I have to write \\ to search for this character. `new Regex("\{2,})"` is an invalid escape equence and would give me a syntax error.

Comment: My comment is about your last line - the directory separator character cannot consist of two characters.

Comment: You have to escape it in the regular expression and the C# string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `new Regex(@"\\{2,}")`  and the rest the same.

You need to actually leave the backslash escaped in your regular expression, so you need to produce a string with two backslashes in it.  The two equivalent techniques to produce the correct C# string literal are `@"\\{2,}"` or `"\\\\{2,}"`

Both of those string literals are the string `\\{2,}`, which is the correct regular expression.  Your regular expression calls for one backslash character occurring two times, and you have to escape the backslash character.  At the risk of being pedantic, if you wanted to replace two `a` characters, you would use the regular expression `a{2,}` and if you want to replace to `\` characters, you would use the regular expression `\\{2,}`  because `\\` is the regular expression that matches a single `\`.  Clear as mud?  :)

Comment: I see, this works for strings like `"aaa\\\\\\\\test.txt"` but not for `"aaa\\\test.txt"` - three backslashes still seems to be a problem.

Comment: The string literal `"aaa\\\test.txt"` is the string `aaa\★est.txt` where the ★ is a **tab** character `"\t"`.  In other words:  `aaa`, a single a backslash, a tab, and then `est.txt`.  So I would not expect to be able to replace two backslashes with one, because there is only one to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a demi-god at regex, I would use StringBuilder and do something like this:

```
string txt = "";
int count = 0;
StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in txt) 
{
  if (c == '\')
  {
    count++;
    if (count < 3) 
    {
      bldr.Append(c);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    count = 0;
    bldr.Append(c);
  }
}

string result = bldr.ToString();
```